# Transform Scale doesn't work on elements nested in buttons

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm applying `transform:scale` to the :hover event for an `<img>` element nested within a `<button>` control.

It works in Chrome, but not in Firefox or IE.

Here's the code (below).  Is there a way to make it work in Firefox and IE?

I'd like to keep the effect on the hover event for the nested `<img>` file, but I can put it on the `<button>` if needed.  I'm really just curious if this code can be made to work on FF & IE or if it's a known limitation with those browsers (or non-standard awesomeness allowed by Chrome).

```css
.zoomable {
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms;
  -o-transition: all 500ms;
  transition: all 500ms;
  border: 1px transparent solid;
}

.zoomable:hover {
  border: 1px orange solid;
  transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
}
```

```html
  <button>
    <img src="bogus.png" class="zoomable" />  
  </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set `:hover` on a `button` and keep everything like it is. Just as you said. If you use element that doesn't include interaction like `div` or `span` you can leave `.zoomable:hover` and it will work. It is a button issue since it brings it's native interaction and probably collides with child element hover event.

Comment: Thanks.  I just heard from a colleague that, on Chrome, click events on buttons "fall through" to any child/nested elements, while on Firefox and Internet Explorer, they do not.  I think this might be a related phenomenon.  Anyway - thanks for the response!

Comment: Sure thing. Not a problem. I had to play with it too. Your title made me curious. ;)